# Which phase will be entered firstly after V8 execute the script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

#### Example

```js
// test.js
setTimeout(() => console.log('hello'), 0)

setImmediate(() => console.log('world'))
```

just run `node test.js` by node v12.12.12 on Intel MacBook Pro.
sometimes the output is:

```bash
hello
world
```

sometimes is:

```bash
world
hello
```

#### My Understanding

v8 will run the code firstly, when it meets `setTimeout`, it adds callback to timer phase queue; when it meets `setImmediate`, it adds callback to check phase queue.Then,
event loop starts to work.

So, which phase does event loop starts ? Some people say `Poll` phase.If it's true, event loop finds poll phase queue is empty, but `check` phase queue is not, so `console.log('world')` should be executed, then event loop comes to next iteration and reach at `timer` phase, `console.log('hello')` will be executed.In a word, the output should be always:

```bash
world
hello
```

Actually it's not always like this.

I have read the doc from nodejs official website, but it does't tell me `which phase will be entered firstly after executes the script`.

And this question is not about the difference between `setTimeout` and `setImmediate`. It's all about the phase concept.

To resolve this problem, I have to read `nodejs` source code ? Read pretty difficult cpp code ? Oh not, it feels really crazy.

Any answers will be appreciated!

Comment: How exactly are you executing the script?

Comment: use node v12.12.12 on Intel MacBook Pro.

Comment: Are you really interested in "*which phase will be entered firstly after executes the script*"? Or are you rather trying "*to resolve this problem*" with `setTimeout` and `setImmediate`? But either way, the answer is (as jmrk put it): you should not need to care, this should not be a practical problem.

Comment: But if I don't know "which phase will be entered firstly after executes the script", I can't manage my code in a right order, it might cause some unexpected bugs.As a nodejs developer, is not important to understand the event loop model and know which is the first phase?@Bergi

Comment: No, it is not important. When you are writing an interactive application, you'll need to handle any events in any order. As jmrk said, your code shouldn't rely on a particular order, full stop. "*I can't manage my code in a right order*" - if you have an actual problem with this, please describe your use case. The solution will simply be not to call `setTimeout` and `setImmediate` at the same time if you expect a certain order. If you are having trouble applying that to your problem, please include your actual l code in your question.

Comment: Yes, I agree. When I work, I don't care about the details of event loop, I just care about what event happened, and what callback will be invoked. But it always feels like a black box for me. I don't understand the details of the event loop, I might be unsafe and lost my coding freedom, Nodejs is no more a tool for me, but I look like a toy of Nodejs. By the way, I am just curious about when you get into event loop problem, how to do search the solution? Read nodejs source code, just google, or look around in stackoverflow?@Bergi

Comment: Depends. Usually a web search with the right keywords should lead you to the documentation, a nodejs engineer's blog post, the specification (for web apis, not nodejs) or a stackoverflow topic. Reading the source always helps, to validate an answer or to find the details in the first place, but I've never had a problem that warranted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setImmediate` is [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) and not implemented in V8, so this isn't a V8 question.

https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/understanding-setimmediate/ says:

> A `setTimeout()` callback with a 0ms delay is very similar to `setImmediate()`. The execution order will depend on various factors, but they will be both run in the next iteration of the event loop.

Node docs say for [setImmediate](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#setimmediatecallback-args):

> When multiple calls to `setImmediate()` are made, the callback functions are queued for execution in the order in which they are created.

whereas for [setTimeout](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#settimeoutcallback-delay-args):

> Node.js makes no guarantees about the exact timing of when callbacks will fire, nor of their ordering.

All of which sounds like there isn't a simple answer, and your code probably shouldn't rely on a particular order, which implies that you don't really need to care about being able to predict the order :-)